# Asynchronously process exchange while original payload remain intact

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

We had a requirement to process a file that has more than 100k records. Each record should be generated as XML and saved to DB. We are able implement system which can handle more than 500k records and now we got a new requirement to transform each record into another form of XML and save in another table for audit purposes.

I followed the following approach to implement it. Initially each record is read from flat file, convert to domain contract and then parallelly save to audit table and transform/enrich to another format and save to domain table. Here is the sample route that i am using.

```
        <route>
           <from uri="direct-vm:domainInXML" />
           <setHeader headerName="auditID"><groovy>UUID.randomUUID().toString()</groovy>  </setHeader>
           <!-- aysn transform and save domain XML to audit DB -->
           <inOnly uri="vm:auditInXMLTransformAndDBPersistor"/>
           <to uri="activemq:queue:domianInQueue?disableReplyTo=true"/>
        </route>
        <route>
             <from uri="activemq:queue:domianInQueue" />
             <!-- transform and enrich headers -->
             <to uri="xslt:xslt/convertToInternalDomainContract.xsl />
             <to uri="direct-vm:transformAndSaveTODomainDB"/>
        </route>
         <route>
             <from uri="vm:auditInXMLTransformAndDBPersistor?concurrentConsumers=3" />
             <!-- transform and enrich headers -->
             <to uri="xslt:xslt/convertToAuditDomainContract.xsl />
             <to uri="direct-vm:transformAndSaveTOAuditDB"/>
        </route>
```

Question here is as we are are processing thousands of records, does transformation and persistence of audit XML runs parallelly in another thread while same domain XML is transformed into another format and saved to domain DB?

Will there be any delay? Is there any better approach that you can suggest? When we save audit XML to DB, initially we set status as 'CREATE', and the during transformation,validation and persistence of internal domain fails we need to update status as ERROR in audit table using auditID in header.

During processing when any record(s) fails to be processed due to some error, I tried to update status to ERROR using auditID in header but by that time there are chances of audit XML not made to auditDB. How can solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which database are you using? It might be possible to move this auditing function into a trigger perhaps and then remove this from the camel route. Then again your specification might require you not to do so.

Answer (score 0):

For use cases involving audit wiretap eip comes in handy. You can refer to http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap. per definition from Camel, Wire Tap (from the EIP patterns) allows you to route messages to a separate location while they are being forwarded to the ultimate destination.

Basically wiretap creates a different thread and performs the needed functionality with a copy of the original exchange. Inc case of failure you can use the same wiretap route to perform any update. To confirm it's sequentially processed you can have concurrent consumers set to 1, so that you don't end up in a race condition.

Comment: Thank you shiva. Initially we tried wiretap EIP but it did not help us. When we tried to test it with 2k records, wiretap started processing all the records only after all the messages were processed by original destination. Using inOnly also did the same thing.